# is there a version update log for jenkins plugins?

Tags: jenkins

I need to downgrade plugins after a faulty update, so i wonder if there is a log which shows me previous versions of the plugins before update.

I have searched in /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [plugin].jpi files are zipped like .jar files. So it is possible write a script to get the version info from the properties.